# Conditional with "&" in comaprison string fails

Tags: conditionals, structure

EE 2.9.2, Structure 3.3.17
In running a conditional to compare a page title and it's Structure parent, the conditional returns false if there is "&" or any other punctuation in the string.

```
{if title == "{structure:top:title}}
   do something
{/if}
```

Simple enough?
This works great if there is no punctuation or other special characters in either.
i. e. if the title is "Administration & Finance" the conditional fails. If it is "Administration and Finance", it returns true.
Placing `&amp;` in the title works, but then other Structure tags ( breadcrumbs ) print it out verbose ( I get Administration & Finance ) . Plus I can't expect editors to remember to put code in the title.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm sure there's a better solution, but for an immediate fix you could use something like Streeng to encode both title and structure:top:title variables and save each as stash variables. Then do the conditional with the stash variables. Or query...

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be missing a `"` in your example - putting this back might fix things.  If not, Romans-8 idea of using [streeng](https://github.com/caddis/streeng) seems viable.  Something like:

```
{if {exp:streeng encode="yes"}title{/exp:streeng} == {exp:streeng encode="yes"}{structure:top:title}{/exp:streeng}}
   do something
{/if}
```

Comment: I ended up using ce_string and converting them to url_titles for comparison. That was the only thing that worked.  I was just wondering if there was a bug/glitch somewhere that was causing the initial comparison to fail, with out a plugin.